# Why does this class member variable not change when calling a CUDA kernel function?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda

In a simple test CUDA application, I have a pointer pointing to a list of class instances, and I copy that data to the GPU. I then run a kernel function many times. The kernel function then calls a `__device__` member function for each class instance which increments a variable, `profitLoss`.

For some reason, `profitLoss` is not incrementing. Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 200000

class Strategy {
    private:
        double profitLoss;

    public:
        __device__ __host__ Strategy() {
            this->profitLoss = 0;
        }
        __device__ __host__ void backtest() {
            this->profitLoss++;
        }
        __device__ __host__ double getProfitLoss() {
            return this->profitLoss;
        }
};

__global__ void backtestStrategies(Strategy *strategies) {
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < N) {
        strategies[i].backtest();
    }
}

int main() {
    int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
    int blockCount = 32;

    Strategy *devStrategies;
    Strategy *strategies = (Strategy*)malloc(N * sizeof(Strategy));
    int i = 0;

    // Allocate memory for strategies on the GPU.
    cudaMalloc((void**)&devStrategies, N * sizeof(Strategy));

    // Initialize strategies on host.
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        strategies[i] = Strategy();
    }

    // Copy strategies from host to GPU.
    cudaMemcpy(devStrategies, strategies, N * sizeof(Strategy), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    for (i=0; i<363598; i++) {
        backtestStrategies<<<blockCount, threadsPerBlock>>>(devStrategies);
    }

    // Copy strategies from the GPU.
    cudaMemcpy(strategies, devStrategies, N * sizeof(Strategy), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Display results.
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", strategies[i].getProfitLoss());
    }

    // Free memory for the strategies on the GPU.
    cudaFree(devStrategies);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
...
```

I would expect it to be:

```
363598.000000
363598.000000
363598.000000
363598.000000
363598.000000
363598.000000
363598.000000
363598.000000
...
```

I believe `profitLoss` is not incrementing due to the way I have initialized the objects (automatic storage duration), and I'm not sure of a better way to instantiate these objects and `cudaMemcpy` them over to the GPU:

```
strategies[i] = Strategy();
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to fix this issue or what might be the cause? Thank you in advance!

---

**UPDATE** It appears that for the first 32768 output lines, there is data, and then after that, every line is zero. So I'm possibly hitting some kind of limit.

Comment: Have never seen cuda-code before, so please excuse my ignorance. What is the for-loop from 0 to 363598 supposed to do? But it looks like `backtestStrategies` is being executed `blockCount` * `threadsPerBlock` times: 32 * 1024, similar to the 32768 lines of output you see.

Comment: The for loop from 0 to 363598 represents a loop through 363598 historical data records. And thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 3):

According to your grid dim `blockCount` and block dim `threadsPerBlock` settings, you only launch 32x1024 threads and each thread only updates one instance. That's why you only have 32768 non-zero results at the head of your vector.

To get the expected result, you could either increase the number of GPU threads by increasing the grid dim `blockCount` large enough to cover all `N` elements, or

You could use a for loop in the kernel function to let each GPU thread update several elements until all of them are updated.

The second way is preferred as it has much less block launching overhead. But you may still need a grid dim larger than 32 to fully utilize your GPU.  You could find more details here.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/